# Computer have pixels on screen, freezing then restart

Tags: display, freeze, crash, reboot, pixels

Specs: Rtx 2060 Super
Ryzen 5 3600XT
B550 Aorus Pro
24gb RAM
750W
Windows 10 64bit[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVKAx.jpg)

Comment: Start with updating all your drivers. Include BIOS in this. Go to the manufacturer's support site for this.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers are usually the culprit for something like this. If  you can get to windows and boot into safe mode as this will use the most stripped down version of your drivers. Otherwise, start by downloading new BIOS drivers (you may need another computer or phone for this) and download it to a USB stick. Plug it in. Use the USB and select the file that is the BIOS (It'll probably do this by itself).

Use DDU to get rid of any existing drivers you may have and re-install them from NVidia experience.

This should be all you have to do. I hope I haven't forgotten anything. Good luck!